# Numeric value '"+i+"' is not recognized At Statement.execute in snowflake stored procedure while executing below code?

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is the stored procedure which uses for loop using java script

```
 create or replace procedure test()
    returns varchar
    language javascript
    execute as caller
    as
    $$
    for (var i = 1; i<= 10; i++)
    {
        var command8=` update table a set a.c1='some' from table b where a.source='gg' and b.c2=a.c2 and b.c3=a.c3 and (datediff(year,date(a.etl_create),current_date())= '"+i+"')`
        var stmt8=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command8});
        var rs8=stmt8.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [bidning variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#binding-variables):

```
for (var i = 1; i<= 10; i++)
{
    var command8=` update table a set a.c1='some' 
                   from table b 
                   where a.source='gg' and b.c2=a.c2 and b.c3=a.c3 
                    and (datediff(year,date(a.etl_create),current_date())= :1)`
    var stmt8=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: command8, binds:[i]});
    var rs8=stmt8.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To substitute a variable into a template literal, use `${variable}`.

```
var command8=` update table a set a.c1='some' from table b where a.source='gg' and b.c2=a.c2 and b.c3=a.c3 and (datediff(year,date(a.etl_create),current_date())= '${i}')`
```